# Is it possible to replace the I20 rear parking camera lens

Tags: repair, backup-camera

Someone scratched my car's rear parking camera and broke the lens. However, the camera is still working fine. I'm thinking that the lens would be less expensive than filing an insurance claim, and I'd like to try fixing it myself.

Can anybody help me get started? I think I need to figure out how to get the camera out and then see if it is possible to replace the lens.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing a question. Please check out my edits and see if they make sense to you. Also, can you let us know what car this is on, it it the Hyundai I20? If you could add a photo that would be great too.

Comment: One thing to do would be to go to your local dealer, if you have one, and talk to the parts people. They should be able to help you figure out if the lens is available as an individual part and also if it is separate from the camera. I wouldn't be surprised if the camera and lens were a single unit. If you have wrecking yards (car recyclers) it might be possible to get parts from there.

Comment: @dlu, yes it is hyundai i20. I have added the photo.

Comment: @dlu, Also what I am thinking of purchasing a camera from this http://www.amazon.in/AutoTrends-Waterproof-Vision-Reverse-Parking/dp/B018XOXX8A/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1482572713&sr=1-3 and remove the lens and attach it to my car camera. Is it an bad idea?

Comment: If the camera is still working, then what you're looking for is not actually a lens, but a lens cover. If the lens were broken, you would not have a useable image. This is good news, because even if you cannot purchase a new cover, there are all kinds of way to fab up a piece of glass to protect the actual lens.

Comment: @Lathejockey81, yes camera is still working. Camera still shows the blurred video . As the camera cover is not an ordinary glass, I am keen to know what type of glass it would that clears the blurred video.

Comment: Our definition of "working" is different, lol. If the camera is blurry then the outer cover is indeed a lens. Good luck finding that as it will be specific to that camera, and I highly doubt they're sold separately.

Comment: You may have some success polishing out the scratch with a dab of jewellers rouge.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it is costly. and it is time compulsion work

Comment: actually for the issue you have to replace complete rear camera becoz only lens not come along .

Answer (score 2):

If the image is clear now, you just need a lens cover. If not, it'd likely be easier and faster to buy a new backup camera and put it in. I just checked Amazon, and saw a good number of cameras under $20, with one (on the first page search for "backup camera") for $9.99 delivered w/ Prime membership. Complete kits *including* the monitor were $29 and up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Back up camera should not be very expensive and trying to fix the camera lens will be difficult. First of all, sourcing components like such a small lens isn't gonna be easy, it's almost impossible, I would say. Save time and effort, get the whole camera changed.

Comment: Can you let us know what pricing and effort estimates you made in order to come up with this answer?

Comment: Considering that even $100 mobile phones these days have a camera (or two), the production cost of the camera is minimal. However, the dealership probably wants to make lots on money for such a small and inexpensive part, so I wouldn't be surprised to find out that in fact the whole camera costs as much as a cheap mobile phone!